# Why is my Android splash screen not executing when my app is launched from the device?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

My splash screen activity runs perfectly when executed from my IDE, but when I launch the application from the mobile device, it fails to show the splash screen activity.

Splash Activity:

```
namespace ICA_Deliveries
{
[Activity(Label = "ICA Deliveries", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true, Icon = "@drawable/icaswift")]
public class Splash : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        RequestWindowFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle);

        // Set our view from the "Splash" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Splash);       

    }

    protected override void OnResume()
     {
         base.OnResume();

         Task startupWork = new Task(() => {             
             Task.Delay(1000);  // Simulate a bit of startup work               
         }); 

         startupWork.ContinueWith(t => {
             Task.Delay(3000).Wait();
             StartActivity(new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity)));
         }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()); 

         startupWork.Start(); 
     }       
   }
}
```

Comment: Make sure you are set to launch the splash activity in your manifest. It is probably still set to launch the original activity from the template you used to start the project.

Comment: @TheAnonymous010 Yeah, but Xamarin auto-generates the Manifest upon launch, so all that should be configured properly in my activity attributes. Could it just be a bug with my adb device? I'm using the Nexus 6p

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/working_with_androidmanifest.xml/#Launchable_from_Application_Chooser Explains the auto-generated manifest

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem, for some devices splash is not working. 
  Remove Task related code from your code and use Handler for wait for some time and go to next screen. 
Following code is working for me.

```
public class SplashActivity : Activity
{


    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate (savedInstanceState);

        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.splash);

        Handler handler = new Handler ();
        handler.PostDelayed (gotoMainActivity, 1000);

    }

    public void gotoMainActivity ()
    {

            var intent = new Intent (this, typeof (MainActivity));
            StartActivity (intent);
            Finish ();

    }
}
```